# Uncaught TypeError on methods when using Setters and Getters in Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, class, object, typeerror, getter-setter

I'm trying to use setters and getters in my class to set the url field as an object with its own properties (value, domain, icon), but when I use a string method like "startsWith()" on the url parameter, I am getting the error "**Uncaught TypeError: url.startsWith is not a function**."

I read about setters and getters before trying to do this and understood that to avoid problems with the setter and getter name over the property name, I just have to use the property with a "_" at the beginning of the property name inside the Setter or Getter.

Simple HTML for this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #333;">   
    

    <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
class Url{
    constructor(url){
        this.url = {
            value : url,
            domain : url.startsWith('https://') ? url.split(8) : url.split(7),
            icon : url + 'favicon.ico'
        }
    }

    get url(){
        return this._url
    }

    set url(url){
        this._url = {
            value : url,
            domain : url.startsWith('https://') ? url.split(8) : url.split(7),
            icon : url + 'favicon.ico'
        }
    }
}

const test = new Url("https://youtube.com")

console.log(test.url.domain)
```

Comment: are you assigning `test.url` anywhere?

Comment: Note that browsers nowadays have a complete URL tool built-in.

Comment: Notice that `split` takes a string (or regex) to split on, not a number. What you wanted is `.slice()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the URL string into your constructor function, it builds an object and assigns it to `this.url`.  That will cause your setter function to be called. However, the setter *also* expects a plain string, so you get that exception.

From the constructor, all you really need is

```
this.url = url;
```

to pass the string parameter to the setter.